# SQL Server On Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I just want to know is it possible to delete data from a parent table which do not cause an effect on child table without terminated the relationship.

Are there any other options than `ON DELETE CASCADE`, `ON DELETE NOT NULL`, `ON DELETE NO ACTION` and `ON DELETE RESTRICT`?

Comment: No there is no other clause other than listed above

Comment: Isn't that what `on delete no action` does?

Comment: @ZaheerKhorajiya: oke zaher,  thanks for your answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff: i think its not, because in the article i read before. On delete no action is similiar like on delete restrict. Its prevent you to delete data from a parent which has relationship with child

But Correct me if i wrong

Comment: @user3284126 . . . How misleading.  If you leave out the constraint, then you get the action that you want -- an invalid foreign key reference.  Odd.  I figured such "default" behavior was what `NO ACTION` did.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's the whole point of a `CONSTRAINT` is that it constrains - i.e. restricts - what the data can be.

A foreign key constraint "constrains" the data such that the data in the child table cannot exist unless the data in the referenced (parent) table exists.

The foreign key constraint options are about *how* the constraint is enforced. They don't enable you to turn off enforcement.

- `NO ACTION` prevents parent rows from being deleted where child rows exist.
- `CASCADE` deletes child rows when parent rows are deleted.
- `SET NULL` set's the child row key to null when the parent row is deleted.
- `SET DEFAULT` sets the child row key to default values (these must exist in the parent table).

If you don't want to enforce the constraint, you don't really want a foreign key.

*You don't need a foreign key in order to join* of course. You probably just want to place an appropriate index on the field to accelerate joins.